# How do I get simulation stats printed in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I know there is a SystemVerilog system call that prints out the simulation stats, but I cannot remember it.  I figured it would be useful to capture the answer in StackExchange.

By simulation stats I mean how long the simulation took to run and other performance measures.

What is the system call that prints out simulation stats?

Comment: Thanks.  Modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be tool specific. Many tools have options for collecting different kinds of statistics and different ways of reporting them. Check your user manual.

Comment: Turns out on questa it is the -printsimstats option on vsim.